# Is there some way to determine your Wii's parent region?

Tags: nintendo-wii, region-lock

A friend of my Wife's bought a Wii seconhand from some-person.

They cannot purchase games via the Wii store because they get a message stating that the game is not available in their region.

Since they did not purchase the Wii through a retailer is there some way to

- 1) Change their Wii's region?
- 2) Determine what their Wii's region is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a small [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=change%20a%20wiis%20regeion&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=7Sy&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=fflb&spell=1&q=change%20a%20wii%27s%20region&sa=X&ei=jNKTUJ-PG8-E0QG98IHwDQ&ved=0CC4QvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=172b1d122963d7bd&bpcl=37189454&biw=1280&bih=933), from an [eHow post.](http://www.ehow.com/how_5986398_change-wii-region.html)

> 1. Go to your Wii Channel Menu and select the feature for which you
>      want to change your regional settings. For example, if you want to
>      change the setting for the Forecast Channel, use your Wii remote to
>      select the Forecast Channel. If you need to change the region for
>      the Everybody Votes Channel, click that channel.
> 2. Go to “Settings” and press “A” to select it.
> 3. Go to the “Nearest Location” tab and select “Change."
> 4. Scroll to the bottom of the location list. Select “Choose from other
>      regions.”
> 5. Choose the region nearest you after scrolling through the various
>      regions listed. Select it with your Wii remote and press the “A”
>      button.
> 6. Select the location nearest you from the list by pressing the “A”
>      button.
> 7. Click “Yes” when prompted. If you wan to change the settings, click
>      “No” and make the necessary adjustments.

**Reminder:** Yes, I know there are typos inside the block quote, but this is taken directly from the post listed above.